# Speeding up different parts of a video based on how much activity is happening

Tags: video, video-editing

I have a long video of people in a park. Sometimes in the video there are many people doing lots of things, but other times only a few sitting idle and not doing much (but still active enough to trigger any motion-detection system repeatedly).

I want to speed up this video, not at a constant rate, but rather at a variable rate that depends on how much activity is there in a scene. So when there are lots of people doing a lot of stuff it should speed it up by a factor of, say 2, but when there's only a few people sitting idle chit-chatting it should speed that up by a factor of, say 10. In fact I would prefer this factor to be a continuous function based on activity rather than discreet values based on some threshold.

What programs or techniques could I use to achieve this? I could of course do it manually in video editing software, but I want a way to automate this.

- Windows, any license, paid or free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Motion detection is the sort of thing that [OpenCV3](https://opencv.org/) excels at. There are wrappers for the OpenCV library for C++, [Python](https://www.python.org/) & Java and numerous examples including person detection and motion detection, such as [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/09/pedestrian-detection-opencv/) lovely example of using it for pedestrian detection.

You will probably find [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) better for varying the speed of the video however the multitude of video editing options in FFMPEG is likely to defeat many people so personally I like to use [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) to wrap it all up *and of course OpenCV has the python bindings*.

I would consider sampling your video at some pre-determined interval, say the middle of every 30 seconds clip, using the pedestrian detection, *(or motion detection)*, from OpenCV to determine the number of people, *(or the amount of activity),* then calculate your factor and apply with [moviepy.video.fx.all.speedx](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx/moviepy.video.fx.all.speedx.html?highlight=speed) to get your compressed clip.

*All of the above are available for Windows, Mac & Linux and are Free, Gratis & Open Source with permissive licences.*